# Sum of two rational numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How is the sum of two rational numbers represented as a set? I tried to think it through myself and this is what I arrived at.

$\frac{a}b+\frac{c}d=\{[(x,y)]:y(ad+bc)=xbd\land b,d,y\neq0\}$

or

$\frac{a}b+\frac{c}d=\{[(x,y)]:(ad+bc,bd)$~$(x,y)\land b,d,y\neq0\}$

where

~$=\{((a,b),(x,y)):ay=bx\land b,y\neq0\}$

I'm not sure if this definition is any good or if there is a more natural way to define it so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: Those sets are the same. So, what is your question?

Comment: I know they are the same. I was just using the relation ~ as that was the way they defined rationals when I was taught that. My question was is this definition any good.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition makes sense, but you should omit the $[]$ symbols since you're building the equivalence classes directly as sets. Also, remember that the notation $\frac ab$ is short for $[(a,b)]$, which is short for $\{(x,y):(x,y)\sim(a,b)\}$, so what you wrote is just a longer way of writing $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$.

Either way, after you define addition like this, you need to check that it's well-defined by showing that if $(a,b)\sim(a',b')$ and $(c,d)\sim(c',d')$, then $(ad+bc,bd)\sim(a'd'+b'c',b'd')$.

Answer (score 0):

In your representations, you rely on the assertion that $x = a, y = b \iff bx = ay$. However, this produces the erroneous solution $x = y = 0$ for all $a, b$. $\{[(x, y)]: x = ad + bc, y = bd\}$ works well for your purpose

Comment: Yes, it would fix your definition.